# D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain() always failing with DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I'm creating a hidden window and I'm looking to getting a pointer to `IDXGISwapChain::Present()`. The problem is that I can't get a valid Direct3D10 device, nor a valid swap chain.

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("flhiSTATIC"), TEXT("flh DXGI Window"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 480, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;
ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(scd));

scd.BufferCount = 2;
RECT rcWnd;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcWnd);

scd.BufferDesc.Width = rcWnd.right - rcWnd.left;
scd.BufferDesc.Height = rcWnd.bottom - rcWnd.top;
scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM; // also tried DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB
scd.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
scd.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_CENTERED;
scd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
scd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
scd.OutputWindow = hwnd;
scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
scd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
scd.Windowed = TRUE;
scd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

pD3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain = reinterpret_cast<D3D10CREATEDEVICEANDSWAPCHAIN_PROC *>(GetProcAddress(d3d10, "D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain"));

HRESULT hr = pD3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL /*pAdapter*/, D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, D3D10_SDK_VERSION, &scd, &pSwapChain, &pDev);
// this guy always fails with 0 in both pSwapChain and pDev...
```

Any idea what might be wrong with the above code?

Comment: I think the problem is my failure to register a window class. I'm currently investigating the issue.

Comment: You should validate that ``CreateWindow`` returns a non-zero value.

Answer (score -1):

I completely forgot about the need to create or assign a pre-existing window class :(

That was the problem; lesson learned - always check the return codes of all the calls.

**edit**

I completely forgot to call `CreateWindow` with a **valid** window class, either one I'd previously registered or one that's registered by *someone* within the current module.

Comment: How do you "assign a pre-existing window class"? Could you maybe make your answer more clear?

Comment: @samhocevar - I haven't pasted the place where the window class `flhiSTATIC` is registered not because of brevity, but simply because I never register such a window class; so the `CreateWindow` call fails. It should receive a valid class in order to succeed, either one I create myself, or one I "fish" from other parts of the code through different means (this code I pasted is actually injected into another process).